# Get index of list child relative to parent

Tags: jquery, css, indexing

So I got a `<ol>` and when I click on a list item I want to log the specific index of the item in the console. I tried this code:

```
$("ol").click(function (e) {
  var source = $(e.target);
  var nthchild = source.index() + 1;
  if(source.is("li")){
        console.log(nthchild);
    }
});
```

I added that `+ 1` so I can use that as nth-child afterwards.
But this code isn't working. What's the matter?
Here's my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/xgBeaJ)

Comment: It's not duplicate. His error comes from using <<selectable>> option from jquery UI which interferes with the .click event.

Comment: So I tried `var index = $("ol li.ui-selected").index();
console.log(index);` and that didn't work aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I modified your codepen javascript into this:

$(function() {
    $("#selectable" ).selectable({
        selecting: function(event, ui) {
            console.log($(ui.selecting).index())
        }
    });
})
```

Your click event won't work if you already bind selectable to the wrapper. You have a method inside it called: selecting and it should do the trick.

Hope it helps!